# How to include resource file in cx_Freeze binary

Tags: python, python-2.6, cx-freeze

I am trying to convert a python package to a linux binary (and eventually a windows executable as well) using cx_Freeze. The package has dependency upon multiple egg files, as i understand cx_Freeze doesn't play nice with egg files, so i unzipped the egg files. One of the egg files has a resource string file 'test.resource' in some package 'test.package', to include this resource string file i used -

```
include_files = ['test/package/test.resource']
```

Now i see this file is being copied to the target directory along with the binary but when i try to run the binary i get the error - "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test/package/test.resource'"

The code trying to read the file is doing this:

```
from pkg_resources import resource_string
strings = resource_string("test.package", "test.resource")
```

How can i add this resource file so that it's available to the generated binary?

Comment: Did you unzip the `test` package into the working directory, or somewhere else? If not, you have to use a tuple of `(source_path, target_relative_path)` instead of just a single `path` string. Also, is the package actually named `test.package` at the top level? In other words, do `import test` and `import test.package` work, it's just that `resource_string('test.package', …)` doesn't, or does the former not work either?

Comment: thanks for the reply. I unzipped the 'test' package in the working directory. I see the file test.resource getting copied in test/package/test.resource relative directory to the target directory where binary is placed as part of cx_Freeze invocation. both import test and import test.package should work. The existing call resource_string('test.package', ...) works when the egg file is included in the path

Comment: "should work" or "tested and do work"? We need to figure out whether there's a problem with the way your app is packaged, or with the way `pkg_resources` is working, and the first step there is to see whether `import` and `pkg_resources` are having the same problem or not.

Comment: I put 'import test' and 'import test.package' right before the resource_string() call and they both worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone needs the answer i got it working by using 'zip_includes' instead of 'include_files'

Comment: could you past you setup.py ?

Comment: Your answer is unclear. I tried your suggestion and it did not work!

Answer (score 2):

Since the accepted answer is light on details, I thought I'd provide a solution that worked for me. It does not require that you unzip your egg files, but does not preclude it either.

**The situation**: I have an application that we package with [esky](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/esky) using the `cx_Freeze` freezer, but this information should apply equally well to applications just using `cx_Freeze` directly. The application makes use of the [treq](https://github.com/twisted/treq) library which includes the following line in `treq.__import__`:

```
__version__ = resource_string(__name__, "_version").strip()
```

I use `pkg_resources` to determine the filepath of the `_version` file and manually add it to my `zip_includes`. We make sure it gets placed into its expected location alongside the rest of the `treq` library files. In my `setup.py` file I have:

```
setup(
    name=...,
    version=...,
    install_requires=[
        ...,
        treq==15.0.0,
        ...
    ],
    ...,
    options={
        ...,
        "bdist_esky": {
            ...,
            "freezer_options": {
                # This would be "zip_includes" in options if just using cx_Freeze without esky
                "zipIncludes": [
                    # Manually copy the treq _version resource file into our library.zip
                    (pkg_resources.resource_filename('treq', '_version'), 'treq/_version')
                ],
                "packages": [..., "treq", ...]
                ...,
            ...,
        ...,
    ...,
)
```

**Bonus**: While one does not have to unzip libraries in order for this to work, it seems to be useful enough in general that you might want to always unzip them upon installation (a la `python setup.py develop`). It's a simple matter of adding the following lines to your application's `setup.cfg`:

```
[easy_install]
zip_ok = 0
```

Then, when you run `python setup.py develop`, your dependencies are installed into `site-packages` in their expanded directory form.